# How to get all Property value's Labels of an Wikidata Item?

Tags: java, label, items, wikidata, wikidata-api

How would you request the set of all Properties that an Item has?

Specifically, I'm looking for the English Labels for each Item that is the Value of an Item's Property.

E.g. "[Earth](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q2)":

```
{
    "Challenger Deep",
    "Solar System",
    "oblate spheroid",
    "geoid",
    "World Ocean",
    "Afro-Eurasia",
    ...
}
```

I'm using the Wikidata Toolkit library for now, but I'd take recommendations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to use MediaWiki API with action [wbgetclaims](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=wbgetclaims) to get all properties for each one claim. For example for Wikidata item [Earth (Q2)](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q2) the request will be:

```
https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetclaims&format=xml&props=value&entity=Q2
```

Then you need to parse the response and to take **id** from the `value` for each one `property`. In this example, for property `P1589` the item id is `Q459173`.

The last step is to get all item labels in English by another request. You have two variants, in both of them we use the all item ids from the previous step, separated by pipe `|`:

- **First variant:** by using action [wbgetentities](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=wbgetentities):

  https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&props=labels&languages=en&ids=Q459173|Q544|Q3241540|Q185969|Q715269|Q27527
- **Second variant:** by using action [query](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query):

  https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=pageterms&wbptterms=label&titles=Q459173|Q544|Q3241540|Q185969|Q715269|Q27527

**Update:** I found how to get all item property value's labels by using only one request. The idea is to find all item [links](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Blinks), and then to filter from them only these from [namespace 0](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:List_of_namespaces) which start with Q.

```
https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Q2&generator=links&gplnamespace=0&gpllimit=100&prop=pageterms&wbptterms=label
```

Comment: but can I use Wikidata Query Service SPARQL for this?

Comment: now, it seems that you can directly use the id instead of the numeric-id: <value entity-type="item" numeric-id="459173" id="Q459173"/>